# Wordpress - how to insert code into the head?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a Like button on my Wordpress site. I'd like to use the og:image meta-tag from facebook to display the proper image when somebody likes it. 
I need to add that tag in the head of the page.
So far I have this in single.php:

```
function fb_image_meta($image) {
    return '<meta property="og:image" content="$image" />';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'fb_image_meta', 10, $image_thumbnail);
```

When I look at the source of an article, The meta tag doesn't show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fix your title please. It does not describe the problem, and yes we already know that it's a question.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in functions.php

```
function fb_image_meta($image) {
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="$image" />';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'fb_image_meta', 10, $image_thumbnail);
```

You should take care of `$image_thumbnail` - it must be declared before wp_head. If this is a post thumbnail, you can get it with this code (before the add_action call):

```
global $post;
$image_thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
```

Comment: I have that now, but the same result: nothing :(

Comment: I see that it's not even working when I hardcode the image and get rid of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of Nikolay's answer:

```
function fb_image_meta($image) {
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="$image" />';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'fb_image_meta', 10, 1);
```

Find and replace your wp_head() call (probably in header.php) with this:

```
do_action('wp_head', $fbImage);
```